# Grouping using VBA macro

Tags: vba, excel

I am using Excel 2010 and I would like to group rows of data using VBA. I will be looping through each row to identify the start and end point of the group.  Column A is where I will start.  As you can see below I have a 10 rows.  The beginning of my first group should be `"AAA"`. That group will take in all rows until `"BBB"`.  The next group will start at `"BBB"`, and take in all rows below to `"CCC"`. The 3rd row will start at `"CCC"`, take in all rows below and stop when it meets the blank line.  The groupings should take in any amount of rows given the required group headings.  Once I have these in I want to sort the rows in each group, and then use conditional formatting.

Could you help with the groupings and where to start?

```
   A
 1 AAA
 2 ROW CONTENT
 3 ROW CONTENT
 4 BBB
 5 ROW CONTENT 
 6 CCC
 7 ROW CONTENT
 8 ROW CONTENT
 9 
10
```

Answer (score 0):

This should get you started. It will define each range by looking for your section names and then sort those ranges.

```
' Array of section names...
Dim a As Variant
a = Array("AAA", "BBB", "CCC", "")

Dim i As Long, intStart As Long, intEnd As Long
For i = 0 To UBound(a) - 1

    intStart = Range("A:A").Find(a(i)).Row
    intEnd   = Range("A:A").Find(a(i + 1)).Row - 1

    With Sort
        .SetRange Range(Cells(intStart, 1), Cells(intEnd, 1))
        .Header = xlYes
        .Apply
    End With

Next
```

Comment: Hi Bond, Many thanks for your reply.  This works fine and I have my data grouping, but there are discrepancies further down my column, where the order is not correct, ie , the original report outputs AAA, BBB, DDD, CCC - this can change each time the original report is generated.  I have brought the data into a 2d array (text stored in 1st column, rows are stored in 2nd column) what would be the best way to sort that by rows (2nd column)?